# Inserting PHP html string into TinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im trying to get HTML from my MySQL table inserted into my TinyMCE editor. But I have serious trouble setting up the PHP string into Javascript.

when I just try to insert it like this:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent("'<? echo $description; ?>'", {format: 'raw'});
```

It has trouble with the single quotes and the double quotes in the $description variable. I get unidentified id's in my string because the string gets cut off due to the single and double quotes that are located in the string.

How can I insert this into TinyMCE, which ultimately comes down to how to make a HTML string without cutting of early?

Comment: Escape the characters in the string.  There's plenty of PHP functions for doing that such as htmlspecialchars() and the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply replace those characters:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent("'<? echo str_replace(array('"', "'"), array('\"', "\'"), $description); ?>'", {format: 'raw'});
```

Comment: No this doesnt work because then the code doesn't get identified by TinyMCE and I get source code straight into it. I need to make sure TinyMCE id's the html code.